SV_PrimitiveID in Geometry Shader and Pixel Shader in Dx12
When I learn the system value SV_PrimitiveID,I have a question.
In my realize,SV_PrimitiveID will give each primitive an id.But if I add GS to pipeline and the GS adds new primitive.I want to know if SV_PrimitiveID will give the new primitive an id in PS stage.
Sorry I don't know how to test this question
